# Custom form on front page redirects on error page

Tags: forms

I've created a form in a wordpress page (it's hardcoded in it's template.) This form redirects on the same page as it's on. This form also verifies the data right there, in the template file.

If I put this form on any page, it works. But on the front page, when I submit it, I get a page, with the default template, with only "There has been an error." in it's contents.

So how can I make that form work everywhere? How can I use POST data returned by my form on the front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my form was using some value from the namespace of wordpress. If this problem happens to you, check what id/names you give to your inputs. If it's too general, it might conflict.